# Is there a short way to purge all printer configurations?

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

An Ubuntu 14.04 which I have been maintaining has a lot of non-working printer configurations. I'd like to purge it all and configure only the working ones from the scratch. Any ideas to remove them all preferably via command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stop cupsd:
`sudo stop cups`
then edit the printer configuration:

```
sudo cp /etc/cups/printers.conf /etc/cups/printers.conf.backup
sudo nano /etc/cups/printers.conf
```

Remove all printer information and save.

Comment: For anyone stumbling across this: now you have to do "systemctl stop cups"

Comment: Agreed, we didn't have `systemd` in 2014 :-)

Answer (score 0):

This post was first search result on google for me while searching for a way to remove all printers from cups. I'm adding answer from another forum, that I found useful.

**Edit 1:** Found a small bug while using this command, `lpstat -p` sometimes print multiple lines for one printer eg.

```
printer kyocera01 disabled since Št 22. apríl 2021, 12:13:31 -
    reason unknown
```

To fix this, pipe `lpstat -p` output to `grep '^printer'` before piping to `cut`, to filter lines containing printer names.

```
lpstat -p | grep '^printer' | cut -d' ' -f2
```

**Original answer:**

```
lpstat -p | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs -I{} lpadmin -x {}
```

This way you can also filter printers with `grep`.

```
lpstat -p | cut -d' ' -f2 | grep mcx | xargs -I{} lpadmin -x {}
```

Link to original post: https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/11980/removing-printers-with-a-script